# Download YouTube history

Tags: youtube, export

I would like download all my YouTube history in various formats like CSV. I don't think YouTube allows to do that directly so I've tried to check each Ajax call on this page `https://www.youtube.com/feed/history`, but it seems very difficult to get it automatically. Any ideas?

By the way, I am also having the same problem with my Google search history. Is anyone able to provide a good solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Google provides a way to download your uploaded videos with their "Take Out" archive tool.
[Link here](https://www.google.com/takeout/)

**It is possible with the Youtube API but requires an authenticated GET request.** [Here is more information on how to write one](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_watch_history?hl=en).

Comment: Google's own docs are kind of sparse, but [this page](http://www.dataliberation.org/takeout-products) lists which products Takeout supports. Unfortunately, the search history is not one of them.

Comment: After trying this myself. Phantom42 statement is correct. The search history is not downloaded in Takeout. It does allow you to download all your original uploaded videos.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect this new information. I did find a way but it requires coding a GET request.

Answer (score 2):

An enterprising fellow made [a Python script to do this](https://github.com/zvodd/Youtube-Watch-History-Scraper) using Scrapy.  It can output results as JSON or write to a SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution is to `Save-As` the page as a text file. This is pretty messy, but you get the data. You can clean it up in Excel, Notepad++ or some other text editor. If you are doing it once this might be a workaround.